# Any way to color lines in a Line command?

Tags: graphics3d

Let's say I want to use the following command to plot the following line segments defined by the points:

```
Graphics3D[Line[{{1, 1, -1}, {2, 2, 1}, {3, 3, -1}, {4, 4, 1}}]]
```

How do I make it so that each line segment has a different color? This is just an example but I would want to be able to do it with arbitrarily many points/line segments.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not possible without breaking it up into several `Line` primitives.  What you *can* do with a single line is assign a different colour to each vertex, and let the system interpolate between them along the segments. It's the `VertexColors` option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A possible way:

```
points = {{1, 1, -1}, {2, 2, 1}, {3, 3, -1}, {4, 4, 1}};
lines = Line /@ Partition[points, 2, 1];
colors = RandomColor[Length[lines]];

Graphics3D[Transpose[{colors, lines}]]
```

[image]